# How can I vectorize a function in numpy with multiple arguments?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do a fit to a given function using Scipy. Scipy.optimize.leastsq needs a vectorized function as one of the input parameters. 
This all works fine, but now I have a more complicated function which is not vectorized automatically by Scipy/Numpy.

```
def f1(a, parameters):
    b, c = parameters
    result = scipy.integrate.quad(integrand, lower, upper, (a, b, c))
    return result
```

or to give a closed example numpy.vectorize also does not work with

```
def f2(a, parameters):
    b, c = parameters
    return a+b+c
```

Is there a possibility to vectorize these functions in Scipy/Numpy?

Thank you for any help!
Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not sure what the question is. Python `*args` collects any number of args,
which a function can unpack as it pleases; see
[docs.python.org/tutorial/...](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def f2( a, *args ):
    print "args:", args
    return a + np.sum( args, axis=0 )

x = np.ones(3)
print f2( x, x*2, x*3 )


def quadf( *args ):
    print "quadf args:", args
    return 1

quad( quadf, 0, 1, (2,3) )
```

Comment: Thank you. That was almost what I was looking for. While numpy.vectorize does not work on my function with *args, numpy.frompyfunc accepts it if I tell it the number of input parameters of the function.